# Compare 2 array values in 2 arrays Php

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have deleted the old post to make this more clear. I have 2 arrays that I need to compare and match but only if 2 values per array are the same.

`$array1 = $plugins`
`$array2 = $xml_dump`

A sample of what both arrays look like:

```
$plugins 

Array
(
    [all] => Array
        (
            [ajax-category-dropdown/dhat-ajax-cat-dropdown.php] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Ajax Category Dropdown
                    [PluginURI] => http://www.example.com/ajax/
                    [Version] => 0.1.5
                    [Description] => Generates multi-level ajax. 
                    [Author] => DyasonHat
                    [AuthorURI] => http://www.dyasonhat.com
                    [Title] => Ajax Category Dropdown
                    [AuthorName] => Dya
                )

            [akismet/akismet.php] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Akismet
                    [PluginURI] => http://akismet.com/
                    [Version] => 2.5.3
                    [Description] => Used by millions
                    [Author] => Automattic
                    [AuthorURI] => http://automattic.com/
                    [Title] => Akismet
                    [AuthorName] => Automattic
                )


$xml_dump
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [plugin] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [name] => Ajax Category Dropdown
                    [ex_version] => 0.1.5
                    [ex_date] => 2008-01-03
                    [plugin_url] => http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-contactform/
                    [advisory_url] => http://osvdb.org/show/osvdb/43284
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [name] => WP-ContactForm
                    [ex_version] => 2.0.7
                    [ex_date] => 2008-01-03
                    [plugin_url] => http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-contactform/
                    [advisory_url] => http://osvdb.org/show/osvdb/43284
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [name] => Math Comment Spam Protection
                    [ex_version] => 2.1
                    [ex_date] => 2008-01-03
                    [plugin_url] => http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/math-comment-spam-protection/
                    [advisory_url] => a
                )
```

I need it to return the value ( or return true) only if  $array1 `Name` , `Version`  matches $array2 `name` ,`ex_version`

In the example above you can see that

```
$array1
Name => Ajax Category Dropdown
Version => 0.1.5

///has a match in 

$array2
name => Ajax Category Dropdown
ex_version => 0.1.5
```

I have tried many variations of `array_intersect` but I cannot get it to match 2 values for each array.

Comment: array_intersect is what you probably need

Comment: This is a bit cryptic...

Comment: Yes it was way to cryptic, I completely changed it so hopefully it is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to close this with what ended up being my solution.

I grab the `Name` and `Version` for both arrays and created a new array for each one, that way I could easily use `array_intersect` and manipulate they arrays. So to get this to work I just needed to create two new arrays with the values I wanted to compare.

```
 $a = array();
 $b = array();

 //first foreach loop

 $find_local_plugs = $global_plugins_name . $plugin_version;
 $a[] = $find_local_plugs;

 //second foreach loop

 $find_remote_plugs = $xml_plugins . $xml_plugin_version;
 $b[] = $find_remote_plugs;


 $matches = array_intersect($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right this should do it:

```
array_intersect_assoc(array_intersect($global_plugins, $xml_plugins), array_intersect($plugin_verso, $xml_plugin_version));
```

Your question is very confusing, you are talking about `$array1` and `$array2` but I see four of them!

Anyway, have you tried the following? This is just a wild guess, but...

```
$result = array_intersect($global_plugins, $xml_plugins, $xml_plugin_version, $plugin_verso);
```

If this doesn't work, I suggest you drop your real world arrays and create some simple / small dummy ones instead and provide us with the result you want to archive for the very same dummy data.

Comment: Something like this, but this returns 0 even though both array_intersect  work on their own and return a value.

Comment: @Wyck: Perhaps you need to use `array_intersect()` instead of `array_intersect_assoc()`?

Comment: @Wyck: It would be very helpful if you could share a sample of your array contents and the expected output.

Comment: I tried just `array_intersect()` no dice, I added a dump of the array to OP.

Comment: @Wyck: Thanks, could you also post the array you're expecting?

Comment: @Wyck: Also, if you could post a `serialize()`d version instead of a `var_dump()` you would save us some time recreating the array. =)

Comment: Added but that looks more confusing to me

Comment: @Wyck: Ermm... The thing is you can't really cut a serialized string. :P It will be even harder to unserialize().

Comment: One the arrays ( XML one) is just to long, its hundreds of entries/lines.

Comment: @Wyck: Perhaps you could limit your arrays with to 10 elements or so with `array_slice($array, 0, 10)` and then serialize that?

Comment: @Wyck: Or you could just make up some dummy data with the same structure.

Comment: @Wyck: Check my edit, if that doesn't work I'm sorry but I can't help you without either clearly understanding what you want to do or seeing an input / output example.

Comment: I made an edit to instead just use 2 arrays (instead of nesting) and hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: @Wyck: Now it's way better, but unfortunately I don't think there is a built-in function to do what you want. Personally I would loop through each array (loop within loop) and check if the values in one array match the equivalent ones on the other, if they do add those values to the return array and in the end filter duplicate results with `$result = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $result)))`.

Comment: Yes writing this all out helped lol, I think I might make a function and use `array_uintersect`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?> 
The above example will output:

Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php